# Saving state of web page in HTML5 / Phonegap

Tags: ios, html, mobile, cordova

I've just started making an iPad app using Phonegap.

On one of my pages I access the camera, take a picture, display that picture on the page and then have a number of customisable options (resizing, positioning of other elements that can be dragged on top of the image etc)

Once you click on a different link (tab bar item) however, all of this information is lost and you have to start over once you go back to the photo page. Is there a way to capture the web page in it's current state, or even grab each elements information (position on page, last photo taken etc) individually so that when the user goes back to the next screen, everything loads as it were when the user left the screen.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just a beginner Phonegap developer myself, but I believe you probably want to look into localStorage. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

You'll need to use JavaScript (and perhaps a library like jQuery) to get various data about the page's current state. Once you know them, you should be able to to store them for retrieval in subsequent sessions later via localStorage.

I hope this helps.